# Qt widget com problem

Tags: qt, widget, composite

I have a Rectangle widget, and  a resize box widget, and a text edit widget.  How can I compose them  without using layouts ? I want all of them as a single widget.

Comment: You'll have to make them subwidgets of a custom widget anyway, and then there is no reason not to use layouts.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for how to do a manual layout is in Qt Layout Management [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/layout.html#manual-layout).

Are you sure you can't use one of the standard layouts?  You can make a custom widget with three children positioned inside using a layout (or layouts) and your new custom widget will still be just a single widget.

Comment: I want to specify the locations of other widget myself. Which layout should I use ?

Comment: That depends very much on how you want to lay out your objects.  Can you give a concrete example?